# Get the country id from the name with pycountry

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to get the country id when I give the country's name.

```
import pycountry

pays = "france"

initales_pays = pycountry.countries.search_fuzzy(pays)
print(initales_pays)
```

And the result is

```
[Country(alpha_2='FR', alpha_3='FRA', name='France', numeric='250', official_name='French Republic')]
```

How can I take the `alpha_2`?

Comment: What did you find in the documentation of `pycountry` about this?

Comment: i didn't find my answer in the pycountry doc :s , i found that "germany = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2='DE')" but that doesnt compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the examples shown on the [pycountry page on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/), the properties of a `Country` instance can be accessed as attributes.

In your case this would be:

```
country = initales_pays[0]
country.alpha_2  # 'FR'
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. However `pycountry` is quite slow which can be an issue when dealing with large datasets. There is a faster library called `countrywrangler`.

Here's an example code using CountryWrangler:

```
import countrywrangler as cw

input_countries = ['American Samoa', 'Canada', 'France']

codes = [cw.Normalize.name_to_alpha2(country) for country in input_countries]

print(codes)  # prints ['AS', 'CA', 'FR']
```

**Full documentation**: https://countrywrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/normalize/country_name/

**Disclosure**:
I am the author of countrywrangler.